# Where can I view glassfish source code on the web

Tags: glassfish

I spent about a half hour surfing the various Glassfish web sites, but i was unable to find the source code online.

I don't want to download the code, I just want to look at a couple specific spots.

Is there similar to mxr.mozilla.org?

Answer (score 6):

http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show

Answer (score 4):

It's now here https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/

Comment: Use subversion to checkout the code. For example: svn co https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/3.1.3

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for:

- https://glassfish.dev.java.net/source/browse/glassfish/

EDIT: There seems to be a migration going on java.net, as per:

- http://terrencebarr.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/please-read-java-net-migration-move-it-or-loose-it/

You can use the fisheye:

- https://fisheye4.atlassian.com/browse/glassfish-svn

Probably best to take some tag from the tree on the left.

Comment: The checkout URL (displayed after pressing the checkout button) is https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/ like in @artbristol's answer

Comment: Thanks for the update @KarlRichter - probably the URL was changed since 2010.