# Where to get the source code for Glassfish 3.1?

Tags: java, glassfish-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I view glassfish source code on the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234779/where-can-i-view-glassfish-source-code-on-the-web)

The same question was already asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234779/where-can-i-view-glassfish-source-code-on-the-web) last year, but I didn't want to resurrect it. Recently I bumped into the same problem. It was also asked [here](http://www.java.net/node/645741) back in 2006. And guess what? Nothing has changed. There is still no bundled archive with source code available. The only place I was able to find is [here](http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show). But that just allows you to browse java files one by one, not to download a zip archive or something. That leads me to doubts about 'open sourceness' of Glassfish...

Comment: The page that you linked has a "Checkout URL." And it's no sin to resurrect an old question here.

Comment: if "nothing has changed" then you should have resurrected the old question, that is the preferred thing to do here, not create more duplicate noise

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I mentioned it in the beginning of the post. Wasn't sure, whether it's a good practice on stackoverflow to resurrect old questions.

Comment: @parsifal Well I had some problems with this checkout URL, since it's **https** and so far I had no luck on getting through proxy on my working Linux machine. Moreover, I think many would agree, that it would've been way easier to download the source in a zipped archive.

Comment: I know you mentioned the dupe - it's still a dupe. On SO, "resurrecting"/curating existing questions is the right thing to do.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" comment can confuse new users - it's inserted automatically by the system when users vote to close a question as a duplicate of another question.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Sorry, have seen lots of dupes here. Many moderators don't like when the old question is resurrected. Would never do that again.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Thanks for the info on "possible duplicate" comment. Should I close it myself?

Comment: @jFrenetic - changing the URL from "https" to "http" worked fine for me. And I think you'll find that most open-source repositories give you SCM access but not an archive (offhand I think only SourceForge gives you the tarball option, and that's provided by ViewVC).

Comment: @parsifal no, unfortunately changing from "https" to "http" didn't work for me. Gotta checkout it from another machine. And, by the way, most of the libraries/frameworks that I work with (such as hibernate, primefaces, apache-commons, various testing tools) do provide the source code in zipped archive, which I find very convenient.